# Layout for a user page in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

The standard ("ships with Drupal") user page appears to be compacted into the **$user_profile()** array.  Then, it's unpacked and "printed" (to the screen) by the somewhat terse user-profile.tpl.php template:

```
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
</div>
```

Is there a guide somewhere that would help me understand what the typical internal structure of this array is, and what hooks I might need to employ in order to place DIVs, classes and so forth into it, in order to achieve certain basic design goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88407/how-to-create-a-profile-page. I strongly suggest to use the [Panels](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimgdS7v9LLAhVB_w4KHcZ2DM0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fpanels&usg=AFQjCNEImF_oYnUWgYMJGAPMYkzJKRjdeA&sig2=tK2OXRfoxGUxGu6SSVhMLw) module. It allows you to add blocks, views etc. to your pages and makes theming a lot easier. There are tons of information about Panels on the internet, so I suggest you have a look around first. The following links can be a good start:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/496278
- https://drupalize.me/search?query=panels

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will check it out. 
Have heard conflicting advice about using Panels. Will read more about it as you suggest.